# How to hide chrome address bar on scroll in Flutter web app?

Tags: google-chrome, flutter, flutter-web

In my flutter web application browser address bar is not hiding on scroll. Does flutter supports this feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**try using the inAppWebview**

it opens the webpage without showing any browser specific details.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

[image]